# Couldn't install Python module xarray 2022.3.0 on Conda

Tags: python, pip, conda

I got this error :

> (base) C:\Users\pkaragiannopoulos>pip install xarray==2022.3.0
> Collecting xarray==2022.3.0
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xarray==2022.3.0 (from versions: 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0rc1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.10.0rc1, 0.10.0rc2, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.5, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.10.9, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for xarray==2022.3.0

I need to install that dependency in order to install gempy

I have tried to install the dependency but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Conda resolves dependencies, so it should work to just do

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge gempy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems that it does not work. In the anaconda shell it gives the next result:>echo "NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=0"
"NEWER_VS_WITH_OLDER_VC=0"
C:\Users\>if "0" == "1" (set /p NEWER_VS= 0<"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\\VC\Auxiliary\Build\Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.txt" \Auxiliary\Build\Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.txt"
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
C:\Users\pkaragiannopoulos>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\\VC\Redist\MSVC\"
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.

Comment: Please don't put long code in comments. If it didn't work, then edit your question with a section to fully explain.

Comment: Also, if you have Anaconda **base**, you should be creating a new environment with `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge gempy` ("foo" is arbitrary - name it something memorable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that it doesn t work again. When I import gempy to a Python interface I take this message: 'DLL load failed while importing _device'